# Re: Chat room restrictions

Tags: support

I've been informed, thanks...

*You have 120 seconds to edit your messages.  Only moderators and SE staffs can bypass this restriction; editing/deleting anyone's messages at any time.*

My I submit a request?

Would somebody please delete my second message in my chat room [Higher Order Thinking](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92382/higher-order-thinking) so that I can restate it more grammatically?